# Compiled app using PyInstaller breaks as it cannot import a module I haven't imported

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

**UPDATE: FIXED**. There was a syntax error in one of my script and prolly that caused the problem since after fixing it, everything seemed okay!

So I want to compile a python application that has a web GUI (that I made with Flask). The whole script setting is divided into multiple python scripts, which are named `app.py`, `core.py`, `cctrl.py` and `helpers.py`. I tried to use `pyinstaller app.spec --onefile` to compile the app.

When I run the app, the app shows an error and breaks. Console text-

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 6, in <module>
    from core import ExcelReader, DocReader
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
[10360] Failed to execute script 'app' due to unhandled exception!
```

But I didn't even import any `utils` module or file.

`app.spec` file-

```py
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['app.py'],
             pathex=['path/to/file'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('templates', 'templates'), ('static', 'static')],
             hiddenimports=['jinja2.ext', 'openpyxl', 'docx'],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,  
          [],
          name='reporter',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
```

Imports in `app.py`

```py
import sys
import json
from os import path
from helpers import *
from cctrl import get_section_names
from core import ExcelReader, DocReader
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for
```

Imports in `core.py`

```py
import re
import json
from docx import Document
from cctrl import change_data
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from docx.shared import RGBColor, Pt
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
from helpers import get_file, get_output, get_percentage, get_settings_file
```

Imports in `cctrl.py`

```py
import re
from datetime import datetime
from docx import Document
```

Imports in `helpers.py`

```py
from docx import Document
from os import path, makedirs
from datetime import datetime
```

I tried using hidden imports, using virtualenvs and `--path` but didn't work out. How to fix this issue?

**Edit**: After compiling multiple times, it now shows the following-

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 4, in <module>
    from helpers import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers'
[8236] Failed to execute script 'app' due to unhandled exception!
```

But still I don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Not sure if thats the problem, I had sometimes issues when using Excel stuff in Python. Got around by using hidden imports of their engines via --hidden-import 'xlrd' --hidden-import 'openpyxl' in the pyinstaller parameters

Comment: What environment have you used to compile your script? Have you been using virtual environment?

Comment: @furious_bilbo I used `python -m venv venv` to create virtual environment.
And yeah I activated venv before running pyinstaller

Comment: @Rafeed17 well then. I would check packages versions and play with hidden imports. I used to have such problems with `pyomo` package and hidden imports helped to avoid import errors

Comment: @furious_bilbo It got fixed. I had a syntax error in `helpers.py` and seems like that problem. When I fixed it and compiled it again, the app seemed to be okay.